# Python Name Error - When calling a previously defined function in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, methods

I need help solving this error. 
I have created a class that has different functions in it. My aim is to call certain functions of the class that I have created based on the triggering of specific events.
When my event is triggered I get an error saying Name error.

I am including the code below:

```
class OurHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    # def __init__(self, source):
    #     self.source = source

    def move_epub(self):
        for i in os.listdir(self.source):
            print("Hello World")

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(f"\n\n{self}\t\t {event}\n\n")
        move_epub()

track_this_folder = "pathname"
a = OurHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(a, track_this_folder)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`move_epub` is an [instance method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects), so you need to call `self.move_epub()`

P.S. The next problem you'll have is that `self.source` is undefined in `move_epub`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my code and now it is working.